# Sending html from summernote(jquery) to php mail

Tags: php, email, summernote

I'm using http://summernote.org/, and i want to get the html from summernote and show into a email. so far i'm getting this into the email:

```
Edição de ' . . '' . <p>ASCDS DS DDS<img src=\"http://www.URL.com.br/admin/img/02522a2b2726fb0a03bb19f2d8d9524d.png\" style=\"width: 300px;\"></p><img src=\"http://www.URL.com/checkopen.php\" style=\"width:1px;height:1px\"/>;
```

and this into the elements tab:

```
<div>
Edição de ' .  . '<br>' . &lt;p&gt;ASCDS DS DDS&lt;img src=\"<a href="http://www.URL.com.br/admin/img/02522a2b2726fb0a03bb19f2d8d9524d.png%5C" target="_blank">http://www.<wbr>URL.com.br/<wbr>admin/img/<wbr>02522a2b2726fb0a03bb19f2d8d952<wbr>4d.png\</a>" style=\"width: 300px;\"&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;img src=\"<a href="http://www.URL.com/checkopen.php%5C" target="_blank">http://www.<wbr>URL.com/<wbr>checkopen.php\</a>" style=\"width:1px;height:1px\"<wbr>/&gt;;
```

Sending via jquery.ajax:

```
data: 'texto=' + $('#texto').code()
```

treating on php:

```
htmlspecialchars(urldecode($_POST['texto']));
```

and mail function doing this:

```
$to = $show['email'];
$subject = $titulo;
$mime_boundary = '_x' . sha1(time()) . 'x';
$headers = <<<HEADERS From: Test <email@example.com> MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt$mime_boundary" HEADERS; $message = <<<MESSAGE--PHP-alt$mime_boundary Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' <html><body> Edição de ' . $data . '<br/>' . $content; </body></html>--PHP-alt$mime_boundary-- MESSAGE; mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

According to what's showing in chrome console above, what do i need to do to correct those problems? I could try replace but i think is not going to work properly.

Comment: are you getting problem in $_POST['texto'] ?
post your data of $_POST['texto']

Comment: what showing in chrome console ? Which one of them is is the content of  texto ?

Comment: @anujnehra 
From chrome console Form Data to $_POST['texto']: <p><img src="URL.com.br/admin/img/da4fb5c6e93e74d3df8527599fa62642.png"; style="width: 300px;">sa<span style="font-weight: bold;">dasd</span>sdssa<br></p>